# What is the difference between installing Virtualbox with or without third-party repository

Tags: apt, virtualbox, ppa, 20.04

In many linux distributions (at least the ones based on debian), virtualbox can be installed directly in console with or without third-party repository, example:

Ubuntu repo:

```
apt install virtualbox virtualbox-ext-pack
```

or vbox repo:

```
echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian $(lsb_release -sc) contrib" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | apt-key add -
apt -y install virtualbox-6.1
export VBOX_VER=`VBoxManage --version|awk -Fr '{print $1}'`
wget -c http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/$VBOX_VER/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-$VBOX_VER.vbox-extpack
VBoxManage extpack install Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-$VBOX_VER.vbox-extpack
```

What is the difference between both installation methods and which is the most recommended?

**Very Important:**

The question is **NOT** about why virtualbox doesn't work properly in Ubuntu 20.04, from ubuntu repo (I know it doesn't work as it should. See bug discussion [HERE](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/690687)). **The question is about the installation methods and the differences between two methods**. For example why in some distributions (or versions) it works well with Ubuntu repo and in others virtualbox repo is necessary because Ubuntu repo does not work as it should

Comment: The one from virtualbox can have a newer version than the one from Ubuntu.

Comment: Until about four years ago, many folks installed Vbox from the upstream source in order to get specific new features -- one big feature was USB pass-through. Those features filtered naturally into the Ubuntu version long ago. I'm not sure why so many random websites still insist on adding Vbox using the upstream deb source, but I suspect it's inertia from those old days.

Comment: @user535733 thanks. Update the question to change PPA for third-party repository

Comment: I just installed VB by `sudo apt virtualbox` with no problems.

Comment: And VB works well for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about any PPA containing VirtualBox. Neither of ways mentioned in the question get any PPA involved.

You have two options:

1. Install Virtualbox from Ubuntu repositories.
2. Download a deb file from `https://www.virtualbox.org/`.

Currently there is not much difference which one to install, because both ways will install the `6.1.6` version.

It doesn't make sense to add the source manually, because installing deb with `dpkg` will do it for you.

The difference is from where you will receive updates. In the first case you'll get them from Ubuntu repositories, that may get updates with delays or stop updating at some point.

In the second case, an update source from `virtualbox` will be set up.

But if you are using an older Ubuntu release, or later with the `20.04` the difference will be with VirtualBox version. Ubuntu maintainers won't switch for a new major version. And if you want the latest VirtualBox release, installing it from a deb will be the only option.

Regarding that `virtualbox` doesn't have a `focal` deb and the repo, it should be updated soon. In this case I recommend to install from Ubuntu repos for now. You can switch later, if the repos won't properly get updates.

Comment: the question was fixed and PPA was changed to  third-party repository

Comment: Well, it doesn't really matter how you call it. The real question is where to install from: virtualbox or Ubuntu repos. I think I've explained it.

Comment: If so, virtualbox would work fine on ubuntu 20.04 with 'apt' and it doesn't.

Comment: @OrganicMarble that link is in the question

Comment: @ajcg Can you eloborate "it doesn't work". I will check the `apt` install on 20.04 now.

Comment: Pilot6 It does not work as it should (it does not resize, it does not install ext manager correctly, etc, etc). This is not related to the question

Comment: You can ask another question, It doesn't resize because you didn't install guest addons. That has been asked many times.

Comment: guest additions is installed and not working as it should. Please, it's not the question I'm asking. it just doesn't work as it should (same as other versions)

Comment: What is the guest system? I suggest asking another question about "not working as it should". I suspect the addons didn't build properly.

Comment: @ajcg I was confused, I guess there was a discussion about the difference between a repo and a ppa.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I also had that confusion but a 'user535733' cleared it up and fix the post.